# Getting [empty response] from Dialog Flow on Intent Call

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am getting this `[empty response]` as a reply intermittently from Dialog Flow for particular Intent.

How can I overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if there are any responses for this intent?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the response from my internal API and properly binding it. 
As I mentioned above this is happening irregularly.

Comment: Can you add any code snippets or details about your dialogflow setup? There currently isn't enough information to find the cause of your issue.

Comment: Are these coming from replies that you know are supposed to be non-empty?

Comment: In fulfilment, I am hitting my WEB API and getting a response from it. That response I am returning back "conv.ask(LSQuestResult);" 
Now sometimes I am getting this output response properly from dialogue flow but sometimes I am getting [Empty Response]. Note: Every time I am getting a response from my Internal WEB API that I am binding for Dialogflow response. That I ensured  from "execution logs in the Google Cloud Console"

Comment: The above functions I am dynamically calling for other intents as well. But I never got [Empty Resonse].
Is this happening because certain characters or some other possible reason

Comment: I did some research and got to know this is happening because of the 5 seconds response timeout limit in Dialogflow / Api.ai,
Please suggest how can I increase this timeout.